# Android For loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have the following code...

```
String t = " "; 
for(int l=0; l<=5; l++){
    t = "Num: " + l + "\n";
}

VarPrueba.setText(t);
```

I am wanting to loop through a set of numbers, and generate a `String` that lists them all at the end. The output should be something like this...

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Could someone please help me understand how to correct my code.

Comment: First of all this loop runs 6 times and not 5 :) either change the start parameter to 1 or the end condition to <

Comment: Do you want it to show the number for each time the loop processes or all in one block at the end ?

Comment: i just want to show all in one block at the end!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change as follow:

```
t+="Num: " + l + "\n";
```

And the most effective way to do this is to using `StringBuilder`, Something like:

```
StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder(); 
for(int l=0; l<=5; l++){
    t.append("Num:");
    t.append(l+"\n");
}

VarPrueba.setText(t.toString());
```

Comment: +1 StringBuilder is much better for memory. Otherwise you create a new string every time you iterate through the loop.