# How to read multiple file from data app?

Tags: java, android

I have app for read file from data app "asset temp" . this code work fine but i want read multiple file same time like wman.mp3 and ema.mp3 .. how do this ?

```
 InputStream file = null;
            try {

                file = new FileInputStream(DataApp+"temp/wman.mp3");
```

Comment: you can use loop

Comment: how use loop.. ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130609/android-for-loop

Comment: i try this before .. get error ..  can write example code